# MobileWeb - do not minify

Tags: appcelerator, minify, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-studio

I am trying to export my project as a `mobileweb` app, but I do not want the code to minified as I need to run some tests on it.

I can't find a way to package the app without having it minified.

I have seen that if I run the app in the browser, it is not minified. However, I am not able to access the files in the file system as I have no idea to where `http://127.0.0.1:8020/` points.

Does anyone knows how to export a `mobileweb` app without js minification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to build your mobile web app from the command line using the following:

`appc run -p mobileweb`

or

`ti build -p mobileweb`

By default, the `--deploy-type` option will be set to `development` which will not minify the JS code.

At this point you can either set `/path/to/your/project/build/mobileweb` as your web root or copy the files in the `build/mobileweb` directory to your web server.

Answer (score 0):

It appears mobileweb is not supported for the `--skip-js-minify` flag.  It's only available for iOS and Android ([CLI docs](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Appcelerator_Command-Line_Interface_Reference))

Example: `titanium build -p ios --skip-js-minify`

You can watch ticket [TIMOB-14253](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-14253) for updates.